# Problema ao salvar arquivo no Android Lolipop do moto-g segunda geração

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Bom dia,
tenho um aplicativo que funciona normalmente em todas as versões do Android desde-a 2 até a versão do moto-g primeira geração, esse aplicativo é bem simples, eu descrevo os detalhes que preciso adicionar no nome da foto, tiro a foto e ele salva a foto com as informações que eu descrevi, hoje ao tenta utiliza-lo em um moto-g segunda geração o aplicativo faz todo o processo como se tudo estivesse acontecendo de forma correta porém quando vou nos meus arquivos a pasta não esta lá, fiz uma depuração e percebi que ele não consegue criar a pasta "DBQ_LTQ" pasta essa onde salvo as fotos, ele cria e apaga no mesmo instante tentei criar manual e deu o mesmo problema, tentei então mudar o diretório e salvar na página principal da memória interna com outro nome e o erro persiste, desinstalei o aplicativo e a pasta apareceu sem nenhum arquivo, segue o código abaixo:

```
/**
 *  Matheus Henrique Rodrigues de Arruda @ Aperam Inox America do Sul S/A.
 */
package info.androidhive.androidcameraapi;

import java.io.File;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.provider.MediaStore.Images;
import android.text.InputFilter;
import matheus.arruda.msinfo.dev.com.*;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.VideoView;
import android.app.AlertDialog;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    private static final int CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE = 100;
    private static final int CAMERA_CAPTURE_VIDEO_REQUEST_CODE = 200;
    public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE = 1;
    public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO = 2;

    // Diretório para salvar
    private static final String IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME = "AperamApps/Foto-PLQA";

    private Uri fileUri;

    public static  EditText txtum;
    public static  EditText txtoutros;
    private static Spinner spinlado;
    private Button btnCapturePicture, btnRecordVideo, sobrebtn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        txtum = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtum);  
        txtoutros = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtoutros);  
        spinlado = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinlado);
        btnCapturePicture = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCapturePicture);
        btnRecordVideo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRecordVideo);
        sobrebtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sobrebtn);
        txtum.setFilters(new InputFilter[] {new InputFilter.AllCaps()});



        btnCapturePicture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if(txtum.length()==0){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "ATENÇÃO: - O campo Unidade Metálica é de preenchimento obrigatório, favor preencher e tentar novamente.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                else if ( spinlado.getSelectedItem().equals("Selecione:")) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "ATENÇÃO: - O campo Defeito é de preenchimento obrigatório.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else {
                    captureImage();
                }

            }

        });


        btnRecordVideo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(txtum.length()==0){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "ATENÇÃO: - O campo Unidade Metálica é de preenchimento obrigatório, favor preencher e tentar novamente.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                else {
                    recordVideo();
                }
            }
        });



        sobrebtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                setContentView(R.layout.sobre);


                 new java.util.Timer().schedule( 
                        new java.util.TimerTask() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {

                                Intent intent = getIntent();

                                startActivity(intent);
                            }
                        }, 
                        3000
                );
            }
        });



        // Checking camera availability
        if (!isDeviceSupportCamera()) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Erro (7002) Seu dispositivo não possui uma camera.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            // Fecha a activity caso o aparelho não possua camêra
            finish();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Verifica a compatibilidade do telefone
     * */
    private boolean isDeviceSupportCamera() {
        if (getApplicationContext().getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(
                PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)) {

            return true;
        } else {

            return false;
        }
    }


    private void captureImage() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

        fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);

        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);


        startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);


        outState.putParcelable("file_uri", fileUri);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);


        fileUri = savedInstanceState.getParcelable("file_uri");

    }


    private void recordVideo() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);

        fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO);


        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 1);

        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri); 


        // inicia a camêra
        startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_CAPTURE_VIDEO_REQUEST_CODE);
    }


    /**
     * Receiving activity result method will be called after closing the camera
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (requestCode == CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                previewCapturedImage();
            } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                // Alertas
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Você fechou a camera", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            } else {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Desculpe! O aplicativo falhou.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
        } else if (requestCode == CAMERA_CAPTURE_VIDEO_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                previewVideo();
            } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Você cancelou a gravação do video", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            } else {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Desculpe! O aplicativo falhou favor reiniciar a gravação", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
        }
    }


    private void previewCapturedImage() {
        try {
            // // exibe um preview


            // gera mapa
            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();

            // ajusta o OutOfMemory do app a fim de evitar erros

            options.inSampleSize = 8;

            final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileUri.getPath(),
                    options);


        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    }

    // exibe um preview
    private void previewVideo() {
        try {


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }



    /*
     * Cria o ID Uri da foto/video
     */
    public Uri getOutputMediaFileUri(int type) {
        return Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile(type));
    }

    /*
     * Retorna com a foto/video
     */
    private static File getOutputMediaFile(int type) {

        // Seta o diretorio externo
        File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME);

        // Cria diretoria
        if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
            if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
                Log.d(IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME, "Erro: (7001) Entre em contato com o administrador "
                        + IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME + " directory");
                return null;
            }
        }




        String unidademetalica = ((String) txtum.getText().toString());
        String outrasinformacoes = ((String) txtoutros.getText().toString());
        String lado = spinlado.getSelectedItem().toString();


        // Cria arquivo

        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy_HHmmss",
                Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
        File mediaFile;
        if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE) {
            mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator
                    + unidademetalica + " Defeito_" + lado + " Outros_ " + outrasinformacoes + " Data_ " + timeStamp + ".jpg");        



        } else if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) {
            mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator
                     + unidademetalica + " Defeito_" + lado + " Outros_ " + outrasinformacoes + " Data_ " + timeStamp + ".mp4");
        } else {
            return null;
        }

        return mediaFile;


    }


}
```

Comment: O Aplicativo chega a parar? Verifique o erro que é emitido no LOG Cat e poste aqui.

Comment: Essa versão tem novas implementações de segurança, já verificou a documentação?

Comment: Bom dia, o aplicativo não trava, ele funciona como se tudo ocorresse bem, na depuração eu percebi que o aplicativo não trava pois ele cria a pasta e o arquivo, só que logo em seguida a pasta e o arquivo é deletada.

@rubStack, não cheguei a lê ainda.

Comment: Dá uma olhada na documentação do método que você está usando, como o @rubStackOverflow disse, foram adicionadas novas funcionalidades de segurança nessa versão.